# Java Huge data store

Tags: java

I have a requirement to store huge amount of data in Java/collection API. Which would be suitable for that Array or Arraylist. And why

Comment: what is the nature of the data? do you need random access? will it be manipulated in any way? will it be accessed a lot? an array may not be the best structure.

Comment: Array vs ArrayList: Does not make that much of a difference.

Comment: what is huge? it's a relative term

Comment: An ArrayList uses an array so the size limit is the same. Are you talking about more than 2 billion etries?

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` are typed safe collection and once you created it can not grow or shrink so better to use `ArrayList` but again if you know the collection is fixed length and type of objects are same then you can prefer `Array`.

You can use `LinkedList` also if you have modify you collection frequently.

It totally depends on your requirement and type of data to be stored.